# watir couldn't find a link with a classname given on a popup (div popup - not new window)

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

```
        $browser.links.each do |link|
          puts link.attribute_value("class")
          if link.attribute_value("class")=='btn btn-success nextStep'
            link.click
          end
        end
```

The code above prints all the classnames of links (yay...)but when it triggers the click event for btn btn-success nextStep - it says element not visible. If i add `when_present.click` ...times out.

```
Error:
btn btn-success nextStep
[remote server] file:///var/folders/3w/b7rcpqfj7kl3wtv56jt99yx00000gn/T/webdriver-profile20120924-3889-1erbmdf/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:5908:in `unknown': Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError)
```

I tried

> $browser.link(:class,'nextStep').when_present.click
>
> $browser.link(:class,'nextStep').click

Comment: Do you have some code for the page that is being tested?

Comment: Did you open the popup before trying to click the link?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error message says the element is not visible. You can get value of class attribute from an element that is not visible, but you can not click it.

Comment: How do i check/print all the visible links?

Comment: Please create a new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590633/watir-print-put-all-visible-links - thanks