# watir print/put all visible links

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

```
$browser.links.each do |link|
          puts link.attribute_value("class")
end
```

How do I get all the visible/existing links in the put statement?

Answer (score 3):

You can also write it by using shorter syntax like this:

```
puts $browser.links.find_all(&:present?).map(&:class_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

This will output value of `class` attribute for all **existing** links on the page:

```
$browser.links.each {|link| puts link.attribute_value("class")}
```

This will output value of `class` attribute for all **visible** links on the page:

```
$browser.links.each {|link| puts link.attribute_value("class") if link.visible?}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you require the class name of the links, you can use

```
$browser.links.each {|link| puts link.class_name if link.visible?}
```

or if you require any specific attribute of the link, you can use

```
$browser.links.each {|link| puts link.attribute_value("attribute_name") if link.visible?}
```